# How to retrieve Azure Key Vault in React JS

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-keyvault

I have created some setting in Azure and I need fetch some secret keys from there in react js

```
const KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');

var KEY_VAULT_URI = "https://mydomain.com.vault.azure.net/";

msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net', msiEndpoint: 'https://vault.azure.net', msiSecret: '69418689F1E342DD946CB82994CDA3CB', msiApiVersion: '' }).then((credentials) => {
    const keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
    var data = keyVaultClient.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, 'My_Secret_Key');
    console.log(data);
});
```

I'm getting some issue *net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*, I think I'm missing something. Could anyone please suggest that how to retrieve that secret keys from Azure in React Js

Comment: Please include the errors you're getting. Be sure to sanitize them before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `loginWithAppServiceMSI()` method from ms-rest-azure will autodetect if you're on a WebApp and get the token from the MSI endpoint. So you must host your code on Azure webapp. Refer to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/) for more details.

```
function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
    return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});
}

function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
    let keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
    return keyVaultClient.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, 'secret', "");
}

getKeyVaultCredentials().then(
    getKeyVaultSecret
).then(function (secret){
    console.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
}).catch(function (err) {
    throw (err);
});
```

If you don't have to use [Managed Service Identity (MSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity), you can use `msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain)` to get the credentials.

```
function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
        return msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain);
    }
```

Comment: error is showing :       Unhandled Rejection (Error): Either provide "msiEndpoint" as a property of the "options" object or set the environment variable "MSI_ENDPOINT" and it must be of type "string".

Comment: @DevSingh Are you running the code in azure webapp or local?

Comment: On local first, when I'll work then after that I'll upload into Azure

Comment: @DevSingh Just as I mentioned, you can not run loginWithAppServiceMSI() locally, ms-rest-azure will autodetect if you're on a WebApp and get the token from the MSI endpoint. Have you tried with `msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain);`?

Comment: Thanks, Let em try all these things

Comment: @DevSingh You are welcome. Feel free to let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: I am using msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain) method, but it gives me cors error.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/82../oauth2/token?api-version=1.0' from origin 'my-azure-site-url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Could you please tell me how can I fix this issue? 
I am doing in React JS App.